# Convert the array of an object into an array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

Convert the array of an object to an array.

My array which I created in JavaScript is based on the **array.push** function. There I got an array in an object, and then I converted it into an array by using **JSON.stringify(myarray):**

```
[PensionLimit] =>
    [
        {"member":1,"pension_name":"1A","min":"N/A","max":"N/A","actual":0,"pension_type":"4","result":"N/A"},
        {"member":1,"pension_name":"1B","min":"N/A","max":"N/A","actual":0,"pension_type":"4","result":"N/A"},
        {"member":1,"pension_name":"1C","min":"N/A","max":"N/A","actual":0,"pension_type":"4","result":"N/A"},
        {"member":2,"pension_name":"2A","min":"N/A","max":"N/A","actual":1,"pension_type":"4","result":"N/A"},
        {"member":2,"pension_name":"2B","min":"N/A","max":"N/A","actual":0,"pension_type":"4","result":"N/A"},
        {"member":2,"pension_name":"2C","min":"N/A","max":"N/A","actual":2000,"pension_type":"4","result":"N/A"},
        {"member":3,"pension_name":"3A","min":"N/A","max":"N/A","actual":0,"pension_type":"4","result":"N/A"},
        {"member":4,"pension_name":"4A","min":"N/A","max":"N/A","actual":0,"pension_type":"4","result":"N/A"}
    ]
```

How do convert it?

My expected output is:

```
[PensionLimit] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [member] => 1
                [pension_name] => "1A"
                [min] => "N/A"
                [max] => "N/A"
                [actual] => 0
                [pension_type] => "4"
                [result] => "N/A"
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [member] => 1
                [pension_name] => "1B"
                [min] => "N/A"
                [max] => "N/A"
                [actual] => 0
                [pension_type] => "4"
                [result] => "N/A"
            )
        [3] => Array
            (
                [member] => 1
                [pension_name] => "1C"
                [min] => "N/A"
                [max] => "N/A"
                [actual] => 0
                [pension_type] => "4"
                [result] => "N/A"
            )
        [4] => Array
            (
                [member] => 1
                [pension_name] => "2A"
                [min] => "N/A"
                [max] => "N/A"
                [actual] => 0
                [pension_type] => "4"
                [result] => "N/A"
            )
        [5] => Array
            (
                [member] => 1
                [pension_name] => "2B"
                [min] => "N/A"
                [max] => "N/A"
                [actual] => 0
                [pension_type] => "4"
                [result] => "N/A"
            )
        [6] => Array
            (
                [member] => 1
                [pension_name] => "3A"
                [min] => "N/A"
                [max] => "N/A"
                [actual] => 0
                [pension_type] => "4"
                [result] => "N/A"
            )
    )
```

Comment: your "Expected output" is not a Javascript array

Comment: He also taged the question with php, and I suppose that setup could work in php

Comment: Expexted output is php while doing form.serialize() i recieve some other data in that type of array

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php ? is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I cant understand it can u please explain

Comment: I believe if you do `$arr=json_decode($CurrentArray);` it will give you your expected output. But I have not tested it.

Comment: It works in json_decode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're trying to convert your JSON to a PHP array, as that is not valid JavaScript output.

In order to do this, PHP provides a function called [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php):

```
json_decode($json, true);
```

When `var_dump`ing the result you'll get almost exactly your expected output.

Comment: There's not much I can help you with, when I know nothing about how you implemented the `json_decode` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a .each() loop:

```
myNewArray = [];
indexOfNestedArray = 0;

PensionLimit.each(function(index1, mySingleObject) {
    mySingleObject.each(function(index2, mySingleObjectSingleValue) {
        myNewArray[index1][index2] = mySingleObjectSingleValue;
    });
    indexOfNestedArray++;
});
```

Comment: Better i expected it in lodash

Comment: here you are:
https://lodash.com/docs#forEach
synthax is different but way how it works the same. Just change the.each( to .forEach(

Comment: sorry it recieve as empty array

Comment: myArrayOfObject in this example is your PensionLimit array.. Did you replace it?

Comment: var myNewArray = [];
   indexOfNestedArray = 0;
   _.forEach(arr,function(index1, mySingleObject) {
       _.forEach(mySingleObject,function(index2, mySingleObjectSingleValue) {
           myNewArray[index1][index2] = mySingleObjectSingleValue;
       });
       indexOfNestedArray++;
   });
   console.log(myNewArray);